# Arduino byte[] to string

Tags: arduino

Hello I am programming a bluetooth connection from Android Studio to Arduino. The connection works and it sends the String. I only get something like this tho on my Arduino (x?xx?xx??xxx?xxx?x) the questionmarks are the other way the string I send is on

This is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPort 11
#define txPort 10
char btData;
String string;

SoftwareSerial btSerial(rxPort, txPort);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  btSerial.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("bluetooth available");
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

if(btSerial.available()>0){
  string = "";
}
while(btSerial.available()>0){
  btData = (byte)btSerial.read();
  if(btData==":"){
    break;
  }else{
    string += btData;
  }
  delay(1);
  Serial.println(string);
}

if(string == "on"){
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
}

}
```

Comment: it should be `if (btData == ':') {`. but `string = btSerial.readStringUntil(':');` would work better

Comment: Ok thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

why do you cast the read to byte??
char it is :)
it should work with 9600 BAUD rate as well

example from my project (I didn't build String though - used single char as command)

```
SoftwareSerial blue(3, 5); // BlueTooth RX, TX;

void BluetoothSetup()
{
  blue.begin(9600);
  blue.print("AT+NAMEKuku"); // give it a name
  delay(2000);   
  Serial.println("got BT");
}
void setup() {
....
BluetoothSetup();
....
}

void loop() {
  if (blue.available()) {
     char r = blue.read();
     ProcessRemoteCommand(r);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Ok tankh you i am going to try that out later.